Why is the bond dissociation energy of C-C greater than C-N when more polarized bonds are stronger?
Why is the bond dissociation energy of $\ce{C-C}$ ($347 \pu{kJ/mol}$) greater than $\ce{C-N}$ ($305 \pu{kJ/mol}$) when more polarized bonds are stronger?

There's covalent and ionic component to bonds. As the data shows, what little ionic component C-N has isn't enough to off-set putting N instead of C. (N is really bad in making single bonds.)

What I mean is if these bonds are components of a structure, there also we consider -C-C- stronger than -C-N= (where N can complete its valency)...

And what else I was talking about? C2 and CN molecules exist somewhere in interstellar medium, but are hardly relevant.
